# Kendo react grid filter conetxtual menu is taking the full page width

Tags: reactjs, react-native, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-react-ui

I have built a table with a custom column menu using kendo react table. My column menu element container max width is 150px but kendo animation container width always taking full page width.

I don't have any styling control to set the width of kendo animation container. We want the context menu as the same as the kendo documentation example. like [this](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/columns/column-menu/) but we are getting it as below

[Screenshot of how it shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO3V3.png)

Please let me know any work around to fix this issue. We are using "@progress/kendo-react-grid": "4.8.0" version.